# Filter data in Listview control with dropdown list for ecommerce site

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I've created a dropdown list server control and have the values Sort Alphabetically A-Z, Z-A, Sort by Price high-low and low to high. The following is the code that I have to bind data into my listview control. How do I modify it so that the data filters according to the dropdown list selection? Also the data isn't bind on the Page Load event. The data only appears after a user has selected a category from the navigation bar which coincides with the parameter that is passed in the function below. I will also include the code front portion of the dropdownlist.

I've created a dropdown list server control and have the values Sort Alphabetically A-Z, Z-A, Sort by Price high-low and low to high. The following is the code that I have to bind data into my listview control. How do I modify it so that the data filters according to the dropdown list selection? Also the data isn't bind on the Page Load event. The data only appears after a user has selected a category from the navigation bar which coincides with the parameter that is passed in the function below. I will also include the code front portion of the dropdownlist.

My Code Behind:

```
protected void BindProductTypes(int productTypeId)
    {
        using (Model1Container context = new Model1Container())
        {
            var data = (from pro in context.Products
                        where pro.ProductTypeId == productTypeId
                        select new
                        {
                            Pic = pro.Photo,
                            Name = pro.Name,
                            Price = pro.Price

                        }).ToList();

            lvItems.DataSource = data;
            lvItems.DataBind();
        }
    }

protected void ddlSorting_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {



    }
```

Comment: How do I take my data variable and filter it by Name, ascending and descending, and also by Price ascending and descending?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `OrderBy` method of `Linq`. And to sort descending you will use `OrderByDescending`. Try this

```
var data = (from pro in context.Products
                    where pro.ProductTypeId == productTypeId
                    select new
                    {
                        Pic = pro.Photo,
                        Name = pro.Name,
                        Price = pro.Price

                    }).OrderBy(x => x.Price).ToList();
```